# Why will the balls experience same acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

> Three identical balls , each of mass m , are pushed by a force F on a
> frictionless table as shown below. Find the net force on each ball.(The balls are not connected in any way).
> [image]

In the solution of this question , it was assumed that the balls will move with same acceleration. I cannot understand how was this assumption made.

Edit : I am posting the solution given in the book .

> Let 'a' be the common acceleration , then      (this is my doubt)
> F=3ma or a = F/(3m)
> Net force on first ball  = ma = m*F/(3m) = F/3
>
> Force by first ball on second ball = (m+m)a = 2m*F/3m = 2F/3
>
> Force by second ball on third ball = ma = m*F/(3m) = F/3

Please provide me the explanation. Thank you

Comment: In order for the first ball to move, the second one has to move as well, it can't be stationary. With this reasoning, the acceleration made upon the first ball must be applied as well to the other two balls.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Is it "I understand that these three balls will move together as if they are attached to each other, but why does it mean that acceleration of the balls is the same?" or "would the balls move together at all? May be they would collide, bounce etc.?"

Comment: the balls are just touching each other. they are not attached to each other . Then why does it seem obvious that the balls will have same acceleration.

Comment: Which ball do you think will be slower (or faster) than the others?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prove this by looking at cases. Let's consider just two balls, and say we push ball 1 into ball 2. Assume the motion is constricted to one dimension.

**Case $1$: $a_1>a_2$**

This means that ball 1 is accelerating through ball 2. This doesn't make sense, as ball 1 cannot exist within ball 2. Therefore, this case is impossible.

**Case $2$: $a_1<a_2$**

This means that ball 2 will move to not be in contact with ball 1 anymore. But then this means that ball 2 is no longer accelerating because no forces are acting on it. So then ball 1 will catch up with ball 2, but then they won't be touching again since $a_2$ will be larger than $a_1$ again. This just doesn't make sense either.

Therefore you are left with only one more possibility: $a_1=a_2$

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation. I cannot understand why Case 2 is not possible. The situation seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @AshokSharma It might be possible if they didn't start off touching, since you could have a series of collisions. But if they start in contact then ball 2 wouldn't suddenly move faster and become out of contact with ball 1.